# How to only fetch entities which contains other entities in Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data

Say we have to entities, A and B.

A has a to many relationship to B, which may be null.

I want to fetch from A only those entities which has Bs. How do I do this?

I tried with a predicate: @"bs != nil", but that didn't work (NSInvalidArgumentException to-many key not allowed here)

Comment: Try @"ANY bs != nil". You always need ANY keyword when you have to many relation. Though in your case you should probably ask if count is larger then zero...